# using loc to sum part columns and not all of them in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

When I am using this:

```
results_all.ix['Total', 'n_Close'] = results_all['n_Close'].sum()
```

the results is this (the results is not summed but rather added):

```
    date           n_Close  g_Close potential
0   2017-05-02.csv  234     10.5    20.5
1   2017-05-03.csv  -8       0      1
Total             234.0-8.0
```

When I use this:

```
results_all.loc['Total']= results_all.sum()
```

the result is:

```
    date            n_Close    g_Close  potential
0   2017-05-02.csv    234       10.5    20.5
1   2017-05-03.csv     -8         0     1
Total   2017-05-02.csv2017-05-03.csv    234.0-8.0   10.50.0 20.51.0
```

The required result will be sum for specific columns:

```
    date            n_Close    g_Close  potential XXX
0   2017-05-02.csv    234       10.5    20.5      10
1   2017-05-03.csv     -8         0     1          7
Total nothing here     226     10.50    21.5     nothing here
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there is problem numeric columns are `string`s.

Solution is convert all values to numeric by [`to_numeric`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_numeric.html), replace original by numeric columns and get `sum`:

```
print (df)
             date n_Close g_Close potential
0  2017-05-02.csv     234    10.5      20.5
1  2017-05-03.csv      -8       0         1
1  2017-05-03.csv     aaa       0         1

df1 = df.apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce')
df.loc[:,  ~df1.isnull().all()] = df1
df.loc['Total'] = df1.sum(min_count=1)
print (df)
                 date n_Close g_Close potential
0      2017-05-02.csv     234    10.5      20.5
1      2017-05-03.csv      -8       0         1
1      2017-05-03.csv     NaN       0         1 <-aaa was replaced by NaN
Total             NaN     226    10.5      22.5
```

Another solution if dont want modify values to numeric:

```
df1 = df.apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce')
df.loc['Total'] = df1.sum(min_count=1)
print (df)
                 date n_Close g_Close potential
0      2017-05-02.csv     234    10.5      20.5
1      2017-05-03.csv      -8       0         1
1      2017-05-03.csv     aaa       0         1 <- aaa for original values
Total             NaN     226    10.5      22.5
```